# Best way of return data from API

Tags: node.js

I looking for the best way or practice to return data from NODE API, i think if is good idea use for example a schema using schm from npm package as follows:

```
const userData = schema({
  name: { type: String },
  age: { type: Number },
});
```

then fill schema and return.
Or return simply data received in JSON format as follows:

```
{
  name: "AARON",
  age: 29,
}
```

My simple question is if exist a best practice to return data between no microservice environment.

Comment: "Best practice" questions typically don't work well on SE. What is "best"?

Comment: Ok, or maybe not the best solution, what's the best recommendation.

Comment: Not sure this is a properly asked question, but there's a chance you're just asking if there are any standards? Like this one, for example? http://jsonapi.org

Comment: What is the backend used for this API?